# Cannot compile Dlib examples with globally installed Dlib

Tags: c++, cmake, dlib

I compiled and installed Dlib as a global shared library with this command `sudo cmake --build . --target install --config Release` then double checked to make sure path `/usr/local/include/dlib` has necessary files there.

I modified `dlib/examples/CMakeLists.txt` a bit to compile with the shared library, most lines below are original:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project(examples)

# Modified lines [1]
#include(../dlib/cmake)
find_package(dlib REQUIRED)
include_directories(${dlib_INCLUDE_DIRS})

macro(add_example name)
   add_executable(${name} ${name}.cpp)
   # Modified lines [2]
   #target_link_libraries(${name} dlib::dlib )
   target_link_libraries(${name} ${dlib_INCLUDE_LIBS})
endmacro()

macro(add_gui_example name)
   if (DLIB_NO_GUI_SUPPORT)
      message("No GUI support, so we won't build the ${name} example.")
   else()
      add_example(${name})
   endif()
endmacro()

add_gui_example(face_detection_ex)
```

The rest of original CMakeLists.txt is removed.

Here is part of the output log (removed repetative parts):

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/face_detection_ex.dir/face_detection_ex.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable face_detection_ex
CMakeFiles/face_detection_ex.dir/face_detection_ex.cpp.o: In function `dlib::entropy_decoder_model_kernel_5<257ul, dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2, 200000ul, 4ul>::decode(unsigned long&)':
face_detection_ex.cpp:(.text._ZN4dlib30entropy_decoder_model_kernel_5ILm257ENS_24entropy_decoder_kernel_2ELm200000ELm4EE6decodeERm[_ZN4dlib30entropy_decoder_model_kernel_5ILm257ENS_24entropy_decoder_kernel_2ELm200000ELm4EE6decodeERm]+0x175): undefined reference to `dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::get_target(unsigned int)'

face_detection_ex.cpp:(.text._ZN4dlib30entropy_decoder_model_kernel_5ILm257ENS_24entropy_decoder_kernel_2ELm200000ELm4EE6decodeERm[_ZN4dlib30entropy_decoder_model_kernel_5ILm257ENS_24entropy_decoder_kernel_2ELm200000ELm4EE6decodeERm]+0x215): undefined reference to `dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::decode(unsigned int, unsigned int)'

face_detection_ex.cpp:(.text._ZNK4dlib10png_loader9get_imageINS_7array2dIhNS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEEEEEEvRT_[_ZNK4dlib10png_loader9get_imageINS_7array2dIhNS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEEEEEEvRT_]+0x7a): undefined reference to `dlib::png_loader::is_gray() const'

face_detection_ex.cpp:(.text._ZN4dlib30entropy_decoder_model_kernel_5ILm256ENS_24entropy_decoder_kernel_2ELm200000ELm4EE6decodeERm[_ZN4dlib30entropy_decoder_model_kernel_5ILm256ENS_24entropy_decoder_kernel_2ELm200000ELm4EE6decodeERm]+0x175): undefined reference to `dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::get_target(unsigned int)'

face_detection_ex.cpp:(.text._ZNK4dlib24compress_stream_kernel_1INS_30entropy_encoder_model_kernel_5ILm257ENS_24entropy_encoder_kernel_2ELm200000ELm4EEENS_30entropy_decoder_model_kernel_5ILm257ENS_24entropy_decoder_kernel_2ELm200000ELm4EEENS_5crc32EE10decompressERSiRSo[_ZNK4dlib24compress_stream_kernel_1INS_30entropy_encoder_model_kernel_5ILm257ENS_24entropy_encoder_kernel_2ELm200000ELm4EEENS_30entropy_decoder_model_kernel_5ILm257ENS_24entropy_decoder_kernel_2ELm200000ELm4EEENS_5crc32EE10decompressERSiRSo]+0x7a0): undefined reference to `dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::get_target(unsigned int)'

face_detection_ex.cpp:(.text._ZNK4dlib24compress_stream_kernel_1INS_30entropy_encoder_model_kernel_5ILm257ENS_24entropy_encoder_kernel_2ELm200000ELm4EEENS_30entropy_decoder_model_kernel_5ILm257ENS_24entropy_decoder_kernel_2ELm200000ELm4EEENS_5crc32EE10decompressERSiRSo[_ZNK4dlib24compress_stream_kernel_1INS_30entropy_encoder_model_kernel_5ILm257ENS_24entropy_encoder_kernel_2ELm200000ELm4EEENS_30entropy_decoder_model_kernel_5ILm257ENS_24entropy_decoder_kernel_2ELm200000ELm4EEENS_5crc32EE10decompressERSiRSo]+0x7bf): undefined reference to `dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::decode(unsigned int, unsigned int)'

face_detection_ex.cpp:(.text._ZNK4dlib24compress_stream_kernel_1INS_30entropy_encoder_model_kernel_5ILm257ENS_24entropy_encoder_kernel_2ELm200000ELm4EEENS_30entropy_decoder_model_kernel_5ILm257ENS_24entropy_decoder_kernel_2ELm200000ELm4EEENS_5crc32EE10decompressERSiRSo[_ZNK4dlib24compress_stream_kernel_1INS_30entropy_encoder_model_kernel_5ILm257ENS_24entropy_encoder_kernel_2ELm200000ELm4EEENS_30entropy_decoder_model_kernel_5ILm257ENS_24entropy_decoder_kernel_2ELm200000ELm4EEENS_5crc32EE10decompressERSiRSo]+0x895): undefined reference to `dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::~entropy_decoder_kernel_2()'

CMakeFiles/face_detection_ex.dir/face_detection_ex.cpp.o: In function `dlib::get_serialized_frontal_faces[abi:cxx11]()':
face_detection_ex.cpp:(.text._ZN4dlib28get_serialized_frontal_facesB5cxx11Ev[_ZN4dlib28get_serialized_frontal_facesB5cxx11Ev]+0x9f1c): undefined reference to `dlib::base64::~base64()'
CMakeFiles/face_detection_ex.dir/face_detection_ex.cpp.o: In function `void dlib::load_dng<dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> > >(dlib::array2d<unsigned char, dlib::memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1<char> >&, std::istream&)':
face_detection_ex.cpp:(.text._ZN4dlib8load_dngINS_7array2dIhNS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEEEEEEvRT_RSi[_ZN4dlib8load_dngINS_7array2dIhNS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEEEEEEvRT_RSi]+0x2f68): undefined reference to `dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::decode(unsigned int, unsigned int)'
face_detection_ex.cpp:(.text._ZN4dlib8load_dngINS_7array2dIhNS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEEEEEEvRT_RSi[_ZN4dlib8load_dngINS_7array2dIhNS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEEEEEEvRT_RSi]+0x342d): undefined reference to `dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::get_target(unsigned int)'
face_detection_ex.cpp:(.text._ZN4dlib8load_dngINS_7array2dIhNS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEEEEEEvRT_RSi[_ZN4dlib8load_dngINS_7array2dIhNS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEEEEEEvRT_RSi]+0x3c03): undefined reference to `dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::set_stream(std::istream&)'
face_detection_ex.cpp:(.text._ZN4dlib8load_dngINS_7array2dIhNS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEEEEEEvRT_RSi[_ZN4dlib8load_dngINS_7array2dIhNS_33memory_manager_stateless_kernel_1IcEEEEEEvRT_RSi]+0x43a0): undefined reference to `dlib::entropy_decoder_kernel_2::~entropy_decoder_kernel_2()'

face_detection_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0x3e2): undefined reference to `dlib::image_window::image_window()'
face_detection_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0x98a): undefined reference to `dlib::image_window::clear_overlay()'
face_detection_ex.cpp:(.text.startup+0xac3): undefined reference to `dlib::scrollable_region::set_total_rect_size(unsigned long, unsigned long)'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/face_detection_ex.dir/build.make:94: recipe for target 'face_detection_ex' failed
make[2]: *** [face_detection_ex] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/face_detection_ex.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/face_detection_ex.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: This is all wrong.  You should not modify dlib's CMakeLists.txt to create a shared library.  Just compile it like normal and it will build one.  Moreover, you should use the modern cmake dlib::dlib target rather than the old ${dlib_INCLUDE_LIBS}.

Comment: Err, sorry, read your question wrong :/ Really, all you need to do is change the `include(../dlib/cmake)` line to `find_package(dlib)` and it will work.

Comment: @DavisKing Do you mean even no need for `target_link_libraries(${name} ${dlib_LIBS})` and `include_directories(${dlib_INCLUDE_DIRS})`? I answered my own question with the running CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: Yes. Don’t do that.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason, that's because I made a typo `target_link_libraries(my_target ${dlib_INCLUDE_LIBS})`. While it must be `dlib_LIBRARIES` or `dlib_LIBS`, not `dlib_INCLUDE_LIBS`.

The correct CMakeLists.txt is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project(examples)

# Fix error "cannot find -lopencv_dep_cudart"
set(CUDA_USE_STATIC_CUDA_RUNTIME OFF)

# Modified lines [1]
# include(../dlib/cmake)
find_package(dlib REQUIRED)
include_directories(${dlib_INCLUDE_DIRS})

macro(add_example name)
   add_executable(${name} ${name}.cpp)
   # Modified lines [2]
   # target_link_libraries(${name} dlib::dlib )
   target_link_libraries(${name} ${dlib_LIBS})
endmacro()

macro(add_gui_example name)
   if (DLIB_NO_GUI_SUPPORT)
      message("No GUI support, so we won't build the ${name} example.")
   else()
      add_example(${name})
   endif()
endmacro()

add_gui_example(face_detection_ex)
```